# How to display repeater item (list) column by column

Tags: sql, asp.net, html-table, asprepeater

I am trying to create a webpage that displays tables for when a user-defined movie can be seen in a given cinema. Lets say a user searches for "Star Wars ep. 8".

I then provide a list of cinemas, and for each cinema a table like this:

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="7">CinemaA</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Mon</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Tue</td>
      <td>17:45</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Wed</td>
      <td>20:45</td>
      <td>17:45</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Thu</td>
      <td>20:45</td>
      <td>17:45</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Fri</td>
      <td>20:45</td>
      <td>17:45</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Sat</td>
      <td>20:45</td>
      <td>17:45</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Sun</td>
      <td>20:45</td>
      <td>17:45</td>
    </tr>

  </tr>
</table>
```

I am using a repeater to go through all the cinema names. I am then using a nested repeater to get all the dates. I then use another nested repeater to, for all the dates, post the specific 'time' for when that movie will be played.

I would much rather have this format:

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="7">Biografnavn</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tue</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thu</th>
    <th>fri</th>
    <th>sat</th>
    <th>sun</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>20:50</td>
    <td>17:30</td>
    <td>13:30</td>
    <td>14:30</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>12:00</td>
    <td>24:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>19:50</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>12:30</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>09:30</td>
    <td>02:00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now. I am not able to do this in my repeaters because i query with:

```
SELECT    time
FROM      showings_table 
WHERE     movieID = StarWars
  AND     cinemaID = parent.parent.repeater
  AND     date = parent.repeater
```

And my Showings_table look something like this:
movieID, cinemaID, date, time

So it would have rows like this:

- StarWars, CinemaA, 29/6, 09:00
- StarWars, CinemaA, 29/6, 11:00
- Superman, CinemaB, 30/6, 12:00

etc.

I have been looking at this problem for a few days and I am very new to this asp world. My problem is really that html tables are written row for row and want to present my table column for column.

Does anyone have any idea on which approach I should use?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to have us help you find a tool to use, and that is noted as off-topic per [StackOverflow Help Page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please make sure your post follows the rules on the link I sent you. On a side note, maybe you could look into using [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/).

Comment: Sorry for any misunderstandings. I am mainly looking for a new approach or for someone to point me in the right direction. I will look into knockout.js

Comment: Would I be correct in assuming that you're currently running a query, looping through the result set in C# and then running another query for each record in that result set, etc.? I would suggest that you do some research into joins, union clauses, the ORDER BY clause, and the GROUP BY clause. Creative application of these terms should yield a result set that is already formatted like you describe. Then, you'll just need to use C# to do the formatting. This approach runs faster and should be easier to implement, when all is said and done.

Comment: I understand, but what you just said is considered **off-topic** per StackOverflow. It would be better if you at least showed your work, then we will help you out.